# How to wire multiple switches and how to know when to use single or doubl

Tags: wiring

I have a box with three sets of #14 cable black white ground on 2 sets and black red white and ground on the other why would one turn on and the other off at the same time?I can't use both lights at the same time the wire go to a receptacle and 2 lights

Comment: Which wires are doing this, and can you get us a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: It sounds like it is wired wrong, Just a caution since we are not sure of the wiring the feeder could be a multi wire branch circuit (240V from black to red) without a wiring diagram or photo of the connections, it also could part of a 3 way switch loop that was incorrectly wired at this point we are guessing.